# Changing directories in Bash shell with large file names

Tags: bash, navigation

I have to navigate through a series of directories containing software installers. I've written a small bash function that gets me to the main folder that contains all of the builds, but the file names of the sub-directories are ridiculously long.

The main folder is named "release" and contains directories with names like "Build 10 - 0.0.3580 - ecb871131857710a". I read William Shotts' Jr's book "The Linux Command Line: A Complete Introduction" and it was very good and thorough, but it didn't really give me any insight into solving this problem and my co-workers don't seem to know of a simpler way either.

Can anyone give me any suggestions or general methods that I could research to help solve this problem? I'm not looking for a script or for someone to give me the full on answer, but a little push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a little long, but not ridiculously so. How long is the full path you need to change to?

Comment: What is _the problem_? You have long filenames, fine. The filesystem can handle them.

Comment: Depends on your OS. Here's a way for Ubuntu: http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/01/28/turn-on-bash-smart-completion/

Comment: Also you could make shortcuts or just rename the directories

Comment: The problem is that my function cd's into the correct directory, but I have to cd with an incredibly long string after that "Build 10 - ..." I could incorporate the build folder into my function, but I'd have to rewrite it every time we released a new build.

Comment: The full path is pretty long as well: /drive/builds folder/Main Build/branchbuild/feature-releasefolder/folder/files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enlightened a guy at school last year by introducing him to the excellence of bash completion while he was reluctantly exploring the superiority of the command line version of Mercurial as opposed to TortoiseHG, per my insistence. The conversation:

> Me: Type cd ~
>
> Him: Yes?
>
> Me: Now tab
>
> Him: And?
>
> Me: slash and tab again.
>
> Him: Oh shitt!
>
> Me: Enter. Pretty nifty, yes? Now type the three first letters of the folder where you saved the files.
>
> Him: Ok?
>
> Me: tab
>
> Him: Oh wow! this is really useful!
>
> Me: The powers of command line...
>
> Him: *cd Sch[tab][enter] cd Proj[tab][enter] cd s[tab][tab][tab]*
>
> Him: It doesn't work
>
> Me: It's case sensitive. Small letters are not the same as big ones. Type Sourc[tab]
>
> Him: Oh. *[tab][enter][tab][enter]*
>
> Me: No, stop that, you can complete the whole paths, not just individual folders.
>
> Him: Oh shittt! This is so cool!
>
> Me: Next I'll show you how to look for files with locate.

I probably changed his whole life and turned his world view upside down!

Answer (score 1):

Linux typically has the following limits:

```
  #define NAME_MAX         255    /* # chars in a file name */
  #define PATH_MAX        4096    /* # chars in a path name including nul */
```

If your "ridiculously long" pathnames are shorter than this you shouldn't have a problem.

I notice that your names contain spaces, so make sure you always quote your variables.

Comment: His question is vague, but I'm pretty sure he's actually asking for a command-line autocomplete.

Comment: Yeah, after reading the other comments, I suspect you're right.

Comment: @Dave In that case, it's off-topic for SO.

Comment: Barmar, I'm not sure how it's off topic. Can you please clarify so I don't make this mistake again?

Comment: Got it, I will adhere to that going forward. Many thanks!